# change the width of error bar caps in pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots

I want to increase the thickness of error bars in my graph using the following command.

```
\pgfplotsset{/pgfplots/error bars/error bar style={ultra thick,black}}
```

However, it does not change the width of the error bar caps as you can see in the picture.[image]

Does anyone know how to fix this?

I use `\newcommand{\myfont}{\fontfamily{cmss}\fontseries{ul}\selectfont}` to make the text font light but it somehow does not do it either. Look at the [J/m^2] unit for instance. Can someone comment on that too?

Here is the complete code I use

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}%fitting functions
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}

\pgfkeys{/pgf/number format/.cd,1000 sep={}}


\newcommand{\myfont}{\fontfamily{cmss}\fontseries{ul}\selectfont}% used with mathpazo 


\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\pgfplotsset{label style={font=\Large},
            tick label style={font=\Large}}

\pgfplotsset{error bars/.cd,
    x dir=both, x explicit,
    y dir=both, y explicit,
    }
\pgfplotsset{/pgfplots/error bars/error bar style={ultra thick,black}}
%\pgfplotsset{/pgfplots/label shift={0pt}}


\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
\begin{axis}[
    enable tick line clipping=false, % makes all ticks same width
    width=9cm,
    height=7cm,
    axis line style=semithick,
    legend style={at={(0.95,0.3)},draw=none},
    legend cell align={right},
    x tick style={black,semithick},
    x label style=
        {at={(ticklabel cs:0.5)},anchor=near ticklabel},
    xmin=0,xmax=20,
    xtick={0,5,10,...,20},
    xtick pos=bottom,
    xtick align=outside,
    y tick style={black,semithick},
    y label style=
        {at={(ticklabel cs:0.5)},anchor=near ticklabel},
    ymin=0,ymax=1000,
    ytick={0,200,...,1000},
    ytick pos=left,
    ytick align=outside,
    xlabel={$h$ [$\mu${\myfont m}]},
    ylabel={$G_a$ [{\myfont J/m}$^2$]}
]
    \addplot [only marks,mark=*,mark options={scale=1.5,fill=black}]
         table [x=x, y=y, x error=ex, y error=ey] {
        x       ex      y       ey
        0       0       0       0
        1.9     0.24        190     8
        7       0.49        515     7
        15      0.73        812     5
    };

    \addplot [only marks,mark=o,mark options={scale=1.5,thick}] table [x=x, y=y, x error=ex, y error=ey] {
        x       ex      y       ey
        1.03    0.09        90      0
        2.2     0.18        180     0
        4.4     0.26        300     0
    };

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}


\end{document}
```

Comment: +1for providing a compilable code (and an interesting question). You can mark the code as code by putting it in the cursor and pressing the `{}` button when editing.

Comment: Thank you for the tip, I'll try it next time. It's been always bothering me)))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this answer, I only address the error bar thickness, I have nothing to say on the font weight. The short answer is that `pgfplots` stacks plot marks at the end, and the width of those is not affected by your choice of the line width. (The longer answer, which I am not going to spell out, would tell you that `pgfplots` nests `tikzpicture`s, as is evident from the code on the top of p. 318 of the manual v1.16. The results of this nesting are IMHO hard to control.) So all you need to do is to define a thicker plot mark

```
\pgfdeclareplotmark{fat-}
{%
  \pgfsetlinewidth{2pt}
  \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{\pgfplotmarksize}{0pt}}%
  \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{-\pgfplotmarksize}{0pt}}%
  \pgfusepathqstroke
}%
```

where the width `2pt` should probably be lowered, and to plug it in.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}%fitting functions
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark,arrows.meta}

\pgfkeys{/pgf/number format/.cd,1000 sep={}}


\newcommand{\myfont}{\fontfamily{cmss}\fontseries{ul}\selectfont}% used with mathpazo 

\pgfdeclareplotmark{fat-}
{%
  \pgfsetlinewidth{2pt}
  \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{\pgfplotmarksize}{0pt}}%
  \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{-\pgfplotmarksize}{0pt}}%
  \pgfusepathqstroke
}%


\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\pgfplotsset{label style={font=\Large},
            tick label style={font=\Large}}

\pgfplotsset{error bars/.cd,
    x dir=both, x explicit,
    y dir=both, y explicit,
    }
\pgfplotsset{/pgfplots/error bars/error bar style={ultra thick,black},
/pgfplots/error bars/error mark={fat-}
}
%\pgfplotsset{/pgfplots/label shift={0pt}}


\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
\begin{axis}[
    enable tick line clipping=false, % makes all ticks same width
    width=9cm,
    height=7cm,
    axis line style=semithick,
    legend style={at={(0.95,0.3)},draw=none},
    legend cell align={right},
    x tick style={black,semithick},
    x label style=
        {at={(ticklabel cs:0.5)},anchor=near ticklabel},
    xmin=0,xmax=20,
    xtick={0,5,10,...,20},
    xtick pos=bottom,
    xtick align=outside,
    y tick style={black,semithick},
    y label style=
        {at={(ticklabel cs:0.5)},anchor=near ticklabel},
    ymin=0,ymax=1000,
    ytick={0,200,...,1000},
    ytick pos=left,
    ytick align=outside,
    xlabel={$h$ [$\mu${\myfont m}]},
    ylabel={$G_a$ [{\myfont J/m}$^2$]}
]
    \addplot [only marks,mark=*,mark options={scale=1.5,fill=black}]
         table [x=x, y=y, x error=ex, y error=ey] {
        x       ex      y       ey
        0       0       0       0
        1.9     0.24        190     8
        7       0.49        515     7
        15      0.73        812     5
    };

    \addplot [only marks,mark=o,mark options={scale=1.5,thick}] table [x=x, y=y, x error=ex, y error=ey] {
        x       ex      y       ey
        1.03    0.09        90      0
        2.2     0.18        180     0
        4.4     0.26        300     0
    };

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That is very helpful, thank you. Do you perhaps have any thoughts on the length as well?

Comment: @Gagik The lengths of the bars at the end of the error bars, i.e. the bars that just became thick?

Comment: The caps, precisely! You made them thick - works. Can you change the length?

Comment: @Gagik Sure, that's easy. Just increase the `mark size`,e.g. `\pgfplotsset{/pgfplots/error bars/error bar style={ultra thick,black,mark
size=7pt},
/pgfplots/error bars/error mark={fat-}
}`

Comment: If only you could help me with the second part of my question regarding the font series `\newcommand{\myfont}{\fontfamily{cmss}\fontseries{ul}\selectfont}`

Comment: @Gagik I am sorry, I can't. So far I never played with the fonts. I believe that this is independent of `pgfplots`, though. Therefore, if you ask a pure font question and do not tag it `pgfplots`, the font experts will see it more prominently and almost certainly answer it.

Comment: That's a good point. I'll try.